# Convert Uint8 (floating-point AUDIO_F32) to int16_t (16bit PCM)

Tags: c++, audio, sdl-2

I am currently trying to record audio and process it using SDL but I am running in to some trouble getting 16bit PCM audio required for the processing step. The device I am running on only supports the AUDIO_F32 format. So my AudioSpec is as follows;

```
SDL_AudioSpec wanted;
SDL_zero(wanted);

wanted.freq = 48000;
wanted.format = AUDIO_F32SYS;
wanted.channels = 1;
wanted.samples = 4096;
wanted.callback = NULL;
```

Now I have to following buffer containing recorded audio;

```
std::vector<Uint8> buffered;
```

How would I go about converting the `Uint8` to the 16-bit PCM format? The `Uint8` should be 32-bit floating point audio defined as a `unsigned char` if I am correct. I have tried the code below but it doesn't appear to give the proper result;

```
std::vector<int16_t> pcm_buffer;
for( const Uint8& sample : buffered )
{
   float sampleFloat = (float) sample;
   sampleFloat *= 32767;

   int16_t sampleInt = (int16_t) sampleFloat;
   pcm_buffer.push_back(sampleInt);
}
```

I have a feeling I am totally misunderstanding what I am doing so I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this real code? I have a hunch that `Uint` should really be `Uint8`. If you're typing this in by hand: consider copy + paste.

Comment: I had to redact part of the code because I was experimenting a lot and my code was/is a mess, but it should be Uint8 indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F32 format is 4-bytes floats, but you have your buffer as buffer of bytes. You miss the step of converting bytes to floats first. This is the wrong line:

```
float sampleFloat = (float) sample
```

Conversion should operate on 4-byte blocks, not on single bytes. Compare:

```
std::vector<Uint8> buffered = ...;
std::vector<int16_t> pcm_buffer;
assert(buffered.size() % 4 == 0);
for(for size_t i = 0; i < buffered.size(); i += 4)
{
     float sampleFloat = *(float*)(buffered.data() + i);
     sampleFloat *= 32767;

     int16_t sampleInt = (int16_t) sampleFloat;
     pcm_buffer.push_back(sampleInt);
}
```

I think it's also reasonable to `assert(buffered.data() % 4 == 0)` as well due to alignment and aliasing rules.

You can also take the cast itself outside of the loop and iterate array of floats, like

```
std::vector<Uint8> buffered = ...;
const float* p = (const float*)buffered.data();
const float* pe = p + buffered.size() / 4;
for (; p < pe; ++p) {
    int16_t sampleInt = *p * 32767;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I feel a bit dumb though >.< Question; why in the second method are you multiplying by 32765 and not 32767?

Comment: Your second suggestion also gives me the following error; `cannot cast from type 'iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<unsigned char *>') to pointer type 'const float *'`

Comment: I fixed the code, end() method was used incorrectly.